# header margin-top cutting off my background image

Tags: html, padding

The titel describes my entire problem. Ive got a header on my page with the margins put at : `margin: 20px 0;`. This makes the distance with the content a nice 20 pixels and the distance with the top of the page as well. The only problem is that my background image does not start below those 20px. If i change the margin to : `margin: 0 0 20px 0` it solves my initial problem but now my header is stuck against the top of the window. Any help is appreciated and my code is below.

HTML

---

```
<body>
  <div class="background">
  <div class="inner">
    <header id="header" role="banner">
          <div class="headerbanner">

          </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
  </div>

        <div class="content contentBackground">
            <div class="contentForm">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="contentChat contentBlock">

            </div>
             <div class="contentOnline contentBlock">

             </div>
            <div class="contentTwitter contentBlock">

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>      
</body>
```

CSS

---

```
.clear{
    clear: both; 
}
.inner{
    width:980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.background{
    background-image:url('THE_IMAGE_URL'); 
    background-color:grey;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
#header{
    height:120px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:70px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  border-radius:10px;
  border: solid 5px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` for your `.background` css class.

```
.background{
    background-image:url('THE_IMAGE_URL'); 
    background-color:grey;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3UBNK/)

Comment: this does fix the margin top problem only now the page gets way smaller. Ill try to fix this myself.

Comment: You can use `width:100%` for `.background` class to make it appear on entire width

Comment: thank you for helping this worked fine. I have to wait 2 minutes before accepting but will then accept this as final answer.